# Entity Framework modelbuilder mapping problems

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I'm having trouble defining my modelbuilder for my entities and throwing an error when trying to set the current values for that entity. The line causing problems down below is:

```
       context.Entry(tEntity.TaskSchedule.ScheduleDaysAndTimes).CurrentValues.SetValues(selectedTask.TaskSchedule.ScheduleDaysAndTimes);
```

I'm throwing an 'The entity type EntityCollection`1 is not part of the model for the current context.'

Heres my setup:

```
public class TaskEntity
{
       [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
       public virtual int TaskId { get; set; }

       public virtual TaskScheduleEntity TaskSchedule { get; set; } 
}
public class TaskScheduleEntity
{
    /*Foreign Key*/
    public virtual int TaskId { get; set; } 
    public virtual TaskEntity TaskEntity { get; set; } 


    public virtual ICollection<ScheduleDayTimeEntity> ScheduleDaysAndTimes { get; set; }

public class ScheduleDayTimeEntity
{
    public int TaskScheduleID { get; set; }
    public virtual TaskScheduleEntity TaskScheduleEntity { get; set; }


    public virtual ICollection<DateTime?> Times { get; set; }
}


 modelBuilder.Entity<TaskEntity>()
            .HasKey(k => k.TaskId)
            .HasRequired(s => s.TaskSchedule)
            .WithRequiredPrincipal(p => p.TaskEntity)
            .WillCascadeOnDelete(true);

        modelBuilder.Entity<TaskScheduleEntity>()
            .HasKey(k => k.TaskId)
            .HasMany(t => t.ScheduleDaysAndTimes)
            .WithRequired(a => a.TaskScheduleEntity)
            .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);

        modelBuilder.Entity<ScheduleDayTimeEntity>()
            .HasKey(k => k.TaskScheduleID);


public void SaveTasks()
    {
        using (var context = new AppContext())
        {
            var tEntity = context.Tasks.First(x => x.TaskId == selectedTask.TaskId);

            context.Entry(tEntity).CurrentValues.SetValues(selectedTask);
            context.Entry(tEntity.TaskSchedule).CurrentValues.SetValues(selectedTask.TaskSchedule);

            context.Entry(tEntity.TaskSchedule.ScheduleDaysAndTimes).CurrentValues.SetValues(selectedTask.TaskSchedule.ScheduleDaysAndTimes); /* Error thrown here*/


            context.SaveChanges();

        }

    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[DbContext.Entry()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg696578%28v=vs.103%29.aspx) is expecting a single entity, and you're giving it an `ICollection<ScheduleDayTimeEntity>`

You need to update your code so you loop through the collection:

```
foreach (var scheduleDayTimeEntity in tEntity.TaskSchedule.ScheduleDaysAndTimes)
{
  context.Entry(scheduleDayTimeEntity).CurrentValues.SetValues(/* Correct Value goes here */ );

}
```